# How can I pull the changes from GitHub without pushing mine?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

The problem is pretty simple. I use source tree to commit my changes, but I'm really a newbie and I don't want to mess up with the common project. What should I do for keep the files I added WITHOUT committing them and at the same time have the master branch updated to the common version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pull never sends your changes to server. Any `git pull` equivalent will do (pull button in source tree)

If you have unstaged files (as I see in your screenshot), save it to a stash, do git pull, and pop the stash.

Command line equivalents are `git stash && git pull && git stash pop`

Answer (score 1):

In order to update your `origin/master` just run `git fetch`. This will sync your `origin/master` with the latest `master` on the remote repository. Then you will be able to compare `origin/master` and your local `master` branches and decide what to do next. You can then `merge` local master with `origin/master` or `rebase` local `master` onto `origin/master` assuming you are familiar with these commands. In order not to mess up your project I would highly recommend to ask for assistance from experienced developers from your team and/or spend some time on learning git. Git is not that simple and it takes time to "feel" it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `git fetch origin master` instead of `git pull origin master`

You can think of `git fetch` as half of a `git pull`. The other half of `git pull` is the merging aspect.

`git pull = git fetch + git merge`

or more clearer:

`git pull origin master = git fetch origin master + git merge origin/master`

---

A one-minute explanation is available on Youtube: 
https://youtu.be/jwyQUfE1Eqw